# C# properties not serialized in designer.cs if its a child-child relation

Tags: c#, visual-studio, serialization, designer

I have absolutly no idea why the designer serialization is not working completly in this scenario.
For me it looks like the designer won't get serialize the 2 second child layer(Parent.ClassProperty.ClassProperty.ValueProperty)

this is what i have(simplified)
`

```
class MyClassA : System.Windows.Forms.Panel
{
   public string Name{get; set;}

   [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
   public MyClassB Property1 {get; private set;}
}

class MyClassB
{
   public string Name{get; set;}

   [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
   public MyClassC Property1 {get; private set;}

   [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
   public BindingList<MyClassC> Test{get; private set;}
}

class MyClassC
{
   public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

`

the expected result in designer.cs is:

`

```
classA1.Name = "Test1";
classA1.Property1.Name = "Test2";
classA1.Property1.Property1.Name = "Test3";
```

`

but i get

`

```
classA1.Name = "Test1";
classA1.Property1.Name = "Test2";
```

`

fun fact: the binding list property serialization for B works fine but not the class C property. i have absolutly no idea why!

Can someone help to pin point the problem?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
[Serializable]
class MyClassB
{
public string Name{get; set;}

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public MyClassC Property1 {get; private set;}

[DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Content)]
public BindingList<MyClassC> Test{get; private set;}
}

 [Serializable]
class MyClassC
{
public string Name{get; set;}
}
```

put  [Serializable] in your class to Serialize

Comment: i have tried for B and A but its still the same. may i need an own designer serializer?